# Add a link to the parent site from the chat

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

Per-site metas have links to the parent site. I think the chat should as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed; the logo now consistently links to the parent site.

Comment: Would it be possible to still have a link back to the chat home page?

Comment: @Simon - every page has this link; "all rooms" in the chat/trasnscript, or "[n] rooms active" everywhere else. The room index is the homepage.